# Which coordinate system does cv2.findHomography uses to find the matrix ?

Tags: opencv

This function takes two two images and finds the Homography matrix that maps one of them into the other. But in doing this calculation which coordinate system do we use. The one of image 1 or the one of image 2? what is the one that is returned.

Comment: Isn't it clear from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography)